# Rotating an Instantiated object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I've hit a bit of a wall with instantiated objects. What I need the engine to do is spawn three prefabs, then at specific times later, flip them over. However, I've been unable to get it working. The spawn code works but when I try adding more to manipulate the prefab, it just gives me loads of errors. The spawn script is inside void Start() while the other script will be in void Update()

Spawn Script:

```
    cardAOne = Instantiate(CardDisplayer.cardList[Shuffle.playerAdeck[0]], new Vector3 (xPosition, yPosition, (zPosition + 3)), Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, zRotation)) as GameObject;
        cardATwo = Instantiate(CardDisplayer.cardList[Shuffle.playerAdeck[1]], new Vector3 (xPosition, yPosition, (zPosition)), Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, zRotation))as GameObject;
    cardAThree = Instantiate(CardDisplayer.cardList[Shuffle.playerAdeck[2]], new Vector3 (xPosition, yPosition, (zPosition - 3)), Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, zRotation))as GameObject;

    cardBOne = Instantiate(CardDisplayer.cardList[Shuffle.playerBdeck[0]], new Vector3 ((0 - xPosition), yPosition, (zPosition + 3)), Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, (0 - yRotation), zRotation))as GameObject;
    cardBTwo = Instantiate(CardDisplayer.cardList[Shuffle.playerBdeck[1]], new Vector3 ((0 - xPosition), yPosition, (zPosition)), Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, (0 - yRotation), zRotation))as GameObject;
    cardBThree = Instantiate(CardDisplayer.cardList[Shuffle.playerBdeck[2]], new Vector3 ((0 - xPosition), yPosition, (zPosition - 3)), Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, (0 - yRotation), zRotation))as GameObject;
```

Movement Script:

```
if (turnA == true) {
        cardAOne.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,0,180);
        cardATwo.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,0,180);
        cardAThree.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,0,180);
    }
```

Comment: where are the error messages?

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" (first line of the movement script)

Comment: Well there two separate scripts,  did you assign values to your objects in the movement script? Otherwise you're trying to acces something that is null.

Comment: So how do I reference the instances then? I thought this was the way to do it (or at least this was the only way that seemed to be doing so without errors) and it was working in that it properly displayed the instances

Comment: Could you show more of your source code because it is very confusing.. You said on first answer that the scripts are inside a hierarchy but how could we figure that out? Moreover, it's not because the parent knows that the child will have it instantiated..

Comment: So apparently it's working now. All I've done is comment the movement script out, move it to a new computer with a current version of unity, and remove the commenting. Now it works. I did not change anything else.

Comment: the simple answer is the movement script is running before the other one.  since your scene is not set up properly, they are happening in "random" order. in fact the spawning one **should call** the other one.

Answer (score 0):

The error is most likely here:

```
if (turnA == true) {
...
```

I think that you just didn't initialize `turnA` before accessing it. Maybe you have some branching code where not every branch assigns a value to that variable.

Concerning coding style:

`if (turnA)` is equivalent to `if (turnA == true)`, but clearer and more conventional.

Comment: Nope, it's properly initialized to true. Plus the errors specifically start on the first rotation line.

Comment: Is card an MonoBehavior object? 
Could you give us a stack trace please

Comment: I don't know how to do a stack trace, but yes, it is declared in MonoBehavior, not in Start() or Void(). I had a set up that did that originally, but it caused too many errors.

Comment: Stack trace happens automatically when an error like this occurs. The stack trace is the part of the error message in the console that tells in which lines and methods the error occured. To provide a stack trace, you can just copy the whole error message.

Comment: No more error because I updated unity. Apparently that was the only issue.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a late answer to this but oh well. No idea what the actual issue was, but updating unity worked. Sometimes it helps to have the most recent software version!

Answer (score -1):

From reading the comments you just need proper reference to the values. There are a few ways of doing this, statics are probably the quickest and easiest.

Set the cards in the spawn script to `public static GameObject cardAOne;`,

then call them from movement script with `SpawnScript.cardAOne.transform.position`.

You could also have a public SpawnScript at the top of your movement file, and you can then drag an drop the instance of it in the inspector from within Unity.

Comment: They're in the same parent script. That shouldn't matter.